# How do i solve this equation of e?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

The problem is to solve for $x$ in $$e^{2x}+2e^x-15=0$$

the book's answer is $x = \ln (3)$

can anyone show how they got this answer? thanks!

Comment: Write $Y = e^x$, solve the quadratic equation for $Y$, and then take the logarithm (of the positive solution) to get $x$.

Answer (score 3):

let $y=e^x$ we have

$y^2+2y-15=0$

then $y=-5$ or $y=3$. then get rid of $y=e^x=-5$

we have

$e^x=3$

$x=\ln3$